# git-tfs: checkin command throw error policy

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, git-tfs

I have a TFS repository on Azure DevOps Server Version 17.143.28621.4
I installed git-tfs V 0.30 downloaded from [github](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases).

I cloned the repository, and I am able to fetch, pull, commit and create shelveset.

I have trouble during the `checkin` operation:

[image]

On my pc I have installed both visual studio 2017 and 2019. I am currently able to checkin to TFS with visual studio.

What I tried:

I have read [this](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/troubleshooting-checkin-policies.md) troubleshooting page, but I can't understand what to do.

This is the result of `git tfs info`:
[image]

I have tried to execute the `enable_checkin_policies_support.bat`. The execution doesn't give error but the checkin command shows the same error.

I also checked, as the troubleshooting says, the registry keys but I didn't find what is shown in the troubleshooting page:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently able to checkin to TFS with visual studio.

According to this [troubleshooting](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/troubleshooting-checkin-policies.md) page, you should known that based on this, this issue caused can be narrow down to `git-tfs` could not find the check-in policy successfully.

---

According to your `git tfs info`, your `TFS client library` is `14` which is `Visual Studio 2015`.

In your PC, you said that the newest version of VS in your machine is `16.0` (`Visual studio 2019`). So, here the `Git-tfs` does not picking the same version of Visual Studio, because:

[image: > Git-tfs by default prefers the newest version of Visual Studio.]

To tell the `Git-tfs` to use the specified client library, just go **Control Panel**, add a **environment variable** `GIT_TFS_CLIENT`, and assign its value as the `visual studio 2015`(in your scenario):

[image]

Comment: Hey, I'm facing this issue as well but i have only VS2019 and i've done the  enable_checkin_policies_support.bat and Loading Hive as well but the checkin policy still occurs :(  so even if i have only 2019, do i still need to set the environment path? I tried setting but it says it couldn't find the path.. to what extend the path folder is needed?